# Where is com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport located (libgdx)

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I am learning libgdx and they talk about this class:

com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport

However it's not in my libs. What do I need to do to get it to work for all platforms? Which jar on which platform etc. I used the project generator to generate the setup for my project.

Comment: Which version are you using?  (Which one did you download, and when?)

Comment: You need to use the latest nightlies. The latest stable version (0.9.9) does not have those.

Comment: I used:

http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2012/04/new-app-libgdx-project-setup/

But there was a choice to use the nightlies instead. Thanks for the info!